# Custom sort comments with select form

Tags: comments, advanced-custom-fields, sort, comment-form

I use ACF Pro to create a customized comments section with additional fields to my custom post type called Products (it's a simple page with a custom comment section, NOT using WooCommerce).

Now visitors to the website can comment by adding a place where you can buy the product. You can add an image, name, price, link, and country for each product, and it works great.

**How it looks**, *(please ignre the random data inside, just for testing purpose)*: https://ibb.co/zh0rWf9

What I want is to be able to sort or filter those comments, by adding a select form with options that will make users able to sort the comments by the country field. **If they select the UK option in select form, then the first comments should be the ones containing 'UK' in the country field.**

Can anybody help me with this?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress DEvelopment Stack exchange. We focus on WordPress development here rather than the support of third-party plugins. You might find better help on the [AFC Pro support page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/support/). If you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an url parameter to define which products are shown, and update the page contents either by javascript or php.